# Soft quota on GPT partition

Tags: virtualization, hard-drive, windows-server-2016, partition, disk-space-utilization

I have a GPT partition on Windows Server which is shared over the network and works with RAID controller. I want it to be extended automatically when it reaches it's limit and users are adding files to this drive.

What is the way to achieve this? Could Quota management be applied on the partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto resizing partitions isn't a common thing. Fully allocate physical disks to the volume. Easier for capacity planning, as you are honest about how big the storage is, and have it all available.

Implement quotas at the file system level, for reports on utilization and controls over the heaviest users. On Windows, [File Server Resource Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/checklist-apply-quota-to-volume-or-folder).